# What is the robust way to create continuation for already exceuting task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Let us have running task `mainTask`. Then something happens and I want to schedule the continuation.

```
mainTask.ContinueWith(continuationTask);
```

But this won't work if mainTask is completed at that moment. <- WRONG STATEMENT
Ok, we could perfrom some check:

```
if (mainTask.IsCompleted)
{
    continuationTask.Start();
}
else 
{
    mainTask.ContinueWith(continuationTask);
}
```

And this is not safe either because we can have task not completed when checking and completed just before creating the continuation.
**Hence comes the question how can task be continued dynamically?**

The only solution I see now is creating the third task:

```
var waitingTask = new Task ( () => mainTask.Wait());
waitingTask.ContinueWith(continuationTask);
waitingTask.Start();
```

But I'd like to know whether more elegant way exists.

Comment: "But this won't work if mainTask is completed at that moment". That's just not true.

Comment: You need to post a self-contained repro to find help. By doing that you'll find out that your assumption is false and that there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: @usr Well, one moment. I'll check this. May be this is my misunderstanding...

Comment: @usr Yep, you are right. Make it as answer I could accept it, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this won't work if mainTask is completed at that moment.

That's not true.

You need to create a self-contained repro to find help. By doing that you'll find out that your assumption is false and that there is a bug somewhere.